# AUGraph with sampler causing a memory leak

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I'm not able to initialize and unitialize an audio graph with sampler without a memory leak. I tried to reduce the amount of code in my example, so the following example doesn't even start/stop the graph. So the code below doesn't really do anything useful, but it shouldn't leak, should it?

```
    AudioComponentDescription cd = {};
    cd.componentManufacturer     = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    cd.componentFlags            = 0;
    cd.componentFlagsMask        = 0;

    AUGraph graph;
    AUNode sNode;
    AUNode IONode;
    // Instantiate an audio processing graph
    result = NewAUGraph (&graph); 

    //Specify the Sampler unit, to be used as the first node of the graph
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Sampler;

    // THESE WOULDN'T CAUSE THE LEAK!!!
    // cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
    // cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HighPassFilter;

    // Add the Sampler unit node to the graph
    result = AUGraphAddNode (graph, &cd, &sNode);

    // Specify the Output unit, to be used as the second and final node of the graph
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;

    // Add the Output unit node to the graph
    result = AUGraphAddNode (graph, &cd, &IONode);

    // Open the graph
    result = AUGraphOpen (graph);

    // Connect the Sampler unit to the output unit
    result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput (graph, sNode, 0, IONode, 0);

    // Initialize the audio processing graph.        
    result = AUGraphInitialize (graph);

    // Uninitialize
    result = AUGraphUninitialize(graph);

    CAShow(graph); // two nodes, 1 connection as expected


    AUGraphClearConnections(graph);
    AUGraphRemoveNode(graph, IONode);
    AUGraphRemoveNode(graph, sNode);

    CAShow(graph); // graph empty as expected

    result = DisposeAUGraph(graph);

    // -------> LEAK!
```

All the return values are ok and the graph works as expected, but I just can't find the cause of the memory leak. This happens only with kAudioUnitSubType_Sampler and not for example with an audio effect.

The leak is 48 bytes and the call tree looks like this (from Leaks-tool in Instruments):

```
0 libsystem_c.dylib calloc
1 libobjc.A.dylib class_createInstance
2 libdispatch.dylib _os_object_alloc
3 libdispatch.dylib dispatch_semaphore_create$VARIANT$up
4 AudioToolbox AudioStreamerImpl::Initialize()
5 AudioToolbox Sampler::Initialize()
6 AudioToolbox AUBase::DoInitialize()
7 AudioToolbox _ZL18AUMethodInitializePv
8 AudioToolbox AudioUnitNodeInfo::Initialize(AudioUnitGraph*)
9 AudioToolbox AudioUnitGraph::Initialize()
10 AudioToolbox AUGraphInitialize
```

Leaked object is called 'OS_dispatch_semaphore'. I'm using iOS 6.1 and this happens in simulator as well as in iPhone 4 and iPad 2. Any ideas what is causing the leak? I've been trying to track down the cause for a couple of days now and it's really driving me nuts :)